# YAML with same 'blocks' in 1 file 2 Java

Tags: yaml

I want to convert a YAML file to 2 java. This worked fine for other files but now i need to convert a file like this:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
kind: type
name: a_name
spec: a_spec
---
kind: other_type
name: b_name
spec: b_spec
```

So these are blocks of config on the same level which i need to convert into an Array of objects.

Any ideas? I'm currently using jackson for the mapping 2 java

Cheers,
Maarten

Answer (score 0):

With some [help](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) and snakeYaml i got it:

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true); // for null values
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(MyClass.class), representer);
List<MyClass> myListOfClass= new ArrayList<>();
InputStream input = this.class.getResourceAsStream(<fileLocation>);
for (Object object : yaml.loadAll(input)) {
    myListOfClass.add((MyClass)object);
}
```